# If statement formula breaking VBA loop code

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet to track jobs that go through the workshop, on a separate sheet i have a macro that will only show live jobs. To determine which jobs to display, on the main sheet i have used an if statement formula like below:

```
=IF(NW3="complete","0","1")
```

so if a job is listed as complete it will show a `0`

I have then written VBA code that will detect if each row in the correct column contains a 1, if so it will copy and paste that row into the live jobs sheet. however the VBA loop code does not recognise the number generated by the IF statement.

I know my code works because if i manually type a 1 or 0 in the columns instead of using the IF formula above, the VBA code finds all the results. I also made a random =SUM statement by dividing a cell by itself to give 1 and then ran the macro and again it worked. So it is only IF statement results it doesn't like.

Im stumped, please help!

Comment: Did you notice that `=IF(NW3="complete","0","1")` puts in a number as a string but `=IF(NW3="complete",0,1)` are real numbers. • If this doesn't solve your issue [edit] the question and add your code please. We cannot provide help on code that we don't see.

Answer (score 2):

`=IF(NW3="complete","0","1")` this formula giving you `1` and `0`0 as text not as number. So, change the formula to `=IF(NW3="complete",0,1)` which will give you output as number. Then `VBA` should work fine.